# How do you differentiate the equation with respect to x?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, derivatives

> How do you differentiate
>   $$\sqrt[3]{\sinh(\sqrt[3]x)}$$
>   with respect to $x$?

This is what I have done:

Define $f(x) := \sinh( \sqrt[3]{x} ) $.  Then
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt[3]{f(x)}\right)
&=\frac13\left(\sinh\left(\sqrt[3]x\right)\right)^{\frac13-1}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sinh\left(\sqrt[3]x\right)\right) \\
&=\frac{\cosh\left(\sqrt[3]x\right)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt[3]x\right)}{3\sinh^\frac23\left(\sqrt[3]x\right)} \\
&=\frac{\frac13 x^{\frac13-1}\cosh\left(\sqrt[3]x\right)}{3\sinh^\frac23\left(\sqrt[3]x\right)} \\
&=\frac{\cosh\left(\sqrt[3]x\right)}{9x^\frac23\sinh^\frac23\left(\sqrt[3]x\right)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to [Math SE!](https://math.stackexchange.com) . Please read this [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)n to begin with and share your thoughts and efforts in the question

Comment: Your question is fine, you should only add the steps you have tried so far.

Comment: It's really quite a straightforward application of the chain rule: the function is $f(g(f(x)))$ where $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ and $g(x)=\sinh x$. So you need the derivatives of $f$ and $g$, and to be confident applying the chain rule to a composite of three functions.

Comment: The best thing you can do is to follow the given suggestions and show you full work here. We'll take a look to it.

Comment: @user I have updated my answer with my trial. Please check if I am correct or not. Thanks!

Comment: @al14643 That’s fine well done! I will add the editing in mathjax.

Comment: @user So is that the correct answer? Thank you for your editing. :)

Comment: @al14643 Perfect answer! I've just edited your solution in MathJax, refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the future.

Comment: @user I really appreciate your kind assistance, thanks for your help!

Comment: @al14643 You are very welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

We need to use chain rule for

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt[3]{f(x)}\right)= \frac13 (f(x))^{-\frac23} \cdot f'(x)$$

and again by chain rule

$$f(x)=\sinh(g(x)) \implies f'(x)=\cosh(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$

Comment: Do you mind showing me with steps? thanks! @user

Comment: @al14643 The steps indicated here should be sufficient for you to obtain the result. You can try to solve by yourself and update your question with the result you obtain. We'll check that and in case will give you some more advice to get a correct solution.